# Missing required module 'CocoaLumberjack' in iOS 8 app / framework

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, cocoapods, cocoalumberjack

I'm having a problem with integrating a cocoa pod (`CocoaLumberjack` in this case) into an iOS app and my own frameworks.

The `Podfile` looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, "8.0"

target "CommonModule" do
    use_frameworks!
    # CocoaLumberjack wasn't officially released with Swift support yet
    # pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack', :git => 'git@github.com:CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.git', :commit => '6882fb5f03696247e394e8e75551c0fa8a035328'
    xcodeproj 'CommonModule/CommonModule.xcodeproj'
end
```

I have a hierarchy of modules (dynamic frameworks) like this:

- `CommonModule`
- `ModelsModule` (has a dependency `CommonModule`)

And finally, the main app:

- `MySwiftApp` (dependency both `ModelsModule` and `CommonModule`)

Now, `CocoaLumberjack` is used in several files in `CommonModule` and works as expected. However, every time I do `import CommonModule` in any file in `ModelsModule`, I get the following compile error:

```
~/Developer/ModelsModule/ModelsModule/SomeFile.swift:2:8: error: missing required module 'CocoaLumberjack'
import CommonModule
       ^
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE:** [Some people](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3095#issuecomment-87836473) Recommend to use [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). I would like to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/405 ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need to ensure that `CommonModule.framework` and `CocoaLumberjack.framework` (and any other frameworks) are listed in the **Embedded Binaries** section of your application target.

All the new iOS 8-style dynamic frameworks must be embedded within your app—even those that you aren't using directly, but that are dependencies of your dependencies—so you might end up seeing references to items you don't recognize.

Incidentally, there is [a new Swift-based logging engine called CleanroomLogger](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomLogger) that might make things easier if you're having trouble interacting with CocoaLumberjack from Swift.

Comment: All frameworks are in `Embedded Binaries` in the main app target.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look in the `CleanroomLogger`. Although, I think I'm going to run into the very same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that CommonModule is swift and that your also using CocoaPods 0.36 as I see your calling `use_frameworks!`.  I'm also assuming that you're using the Obj-C version of CocoaLumberjack, and trying to use it with Swift.  That `use_frameworks!` flag tells CocoaPods to generate frameworks of the pods for linking in your Xcode project.  So you need to say at the top of your class

```
import CocoaLumberjack
```

instead of using the Swift-Bridging-Header

Here is the blog post on [cocoapods.org](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/) where they talk about the how to author a pod for the new `use_frameworks!` flag.  Scroll down to the part **Common Header Pitfalls**

It could also be that your podspec creates a dependency to use CocoaLumberjack, and when linked to your project CocoaLumberjack and CommonModules, but Common Module is not referencing it correctly in the library.  To get past that you need to refer to it as a framework when you import it into your Objective-C library

`#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>`